# Rubymine deprecation warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Does anyone know why according to Rubymine this is acceptable `where({name: 'Jim'})` but this `where(name: 'Jim')` causes a deprecation warning which reads

> "Supplying any condition to the finder or calculation methods is
>   deprecated."

Answer (score 3):

There was [an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13413) in RubyMine 5.4 Beta that is already fixed in the final release.

Answer (score 0):

Because you no longer need to specify a `:conditions` option to the query method `where` as was required with the `find` family of methods before Rails 3.x. You simply pass the Hash of conditions to `where` directly. For example, instead of this:

```
where(conditions: {name: 'Bob'})
```

you can simply call:

```
where(name: 'bob')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response man, but i edited the question as my wording didn't quite read what i needed to get across.

Comment: Where do you see this deprecation warning? Do you see it in the Rails console output, for instance? I'm wondering if it's perhaps a bug in Rubymine instead of a bug in Rails.

Comment: Only in rubymine, in the rail console nope. I have a feeling it may be more of a rubymine bug than a rails issue myself.